# hover ul display block issues, html 4 notepad++

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, mouseover

i'm fairly new to html and I need to create a basic website for my college assignment but I want to go a step up from what everyone is doing and rather then creating a basic navigation menu I decided to create something more interesting and fun, a drop down navigation menu with changing colors and transition effects (HERE IS THE ISSUE) - BUT when i hover over menu the lists do not appear.. here is my html/css codes for that section:

```
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>

ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}
#navmenu a {                    
text-decleration: none;
display: block;
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: ;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 5px; 
font-family: Magneto;
font-size: 20px;
color: ffffff;
transition: ease-in all 400ms;                        
-moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;                                                 
-webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
-o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
}
#navmenu ul {
display: none;
}
#navmenu li:hover ul    {
display: block;
}

#navmenu li:hover > a {                             
background-color: #535ffb;
transition: ease-in all 300ms;
-moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
-webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;                  
-o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
position: relative;                                
left: 10px;
}
#navmenu a {                      
margin-top: 3px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your second ul is not nested under the menu item. Try this:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#navmenu a {
  text-decleration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: ;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Magneto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: ffffff;
  transition: ease-in all 400ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
}
#navmenu ul {
  display: none;
}
#navmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#navmenu li:hover > a {
  background-color: #535ffb;
  transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
#navmenu a {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Interests</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Moogs, that works for me; you are a legend! but whats happening now on the page is that when i hover over it, sure it's working now but now its pushing the other content that on the page down and up when i stop hovering on it? are you able to help with that also? Do i need a div for the navmenu? It just pushed other content up and down as i hover on/off it. Oh and also, if i hover any where to the right of the "menu" it somehow works and it shouldn't so if i hover anywhere to the right of the menu on the page it'll work so i get the feeling that i need to contain it with a div? am i right?

Comment: @lolpopzor The menu probably just needs to be positioned absolute so that it doesn't affect surrounding elements. If you're able to throw the site up on a JSFiddle or send a link then I can probably help you out better